# Exclude header section from cache

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using three types of menu in my Magento header 
Please review the code :

```
<?php
$sessionCustomer    =   Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$identifier         =   Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
$currentRouter      =   Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$getHeaderSession       =   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getHeaderPage();
$pageCoomercial = array('commercial-shop','market-overview','clients-hotels','multi-family-housing','corporate','education-recreation','team-sports','government','privateclubs','medical-wellness','commercial-sales-reps','design','supply','services-service','markets','services','spotlight-installs','ymca-jcc','delivery-install','pro-teams','health-clubs');
    $currentUrl1 = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); 
    $urlArr = explode('/',$currentUrl1);
    if($identifier == 'home'  &&  $currentRouter == 'cms') { 
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsHeaderPage(); 
        include "main-header.phtml";
    } 
    else if($getHeaderSession == 'commercial-shop' || in_array($identifier,$pageCoomercial) &&  $currentRouter == 'cms' || isset($_REQUEST['store']) == 'commercial')
    {   
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsHeaderPage(); 
        include "header-commercial.phtml";          
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setHeaderPage('commercial-shop');           
    }   
    else{
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsHeaderPage();    
        include "header-retail.phtml";      
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setHeaderPage('retail-home');           

    }
?>
```

Now when i am using any cache extesion it's show first visited header menu on all pages.When i disabled cache extesion then this code working fine.where i am wrong ? is this method wright ?.
I have tried to avoid header block from cache but it's not working code is below :

```
<reference name="header">
        <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>
</reference>
```

is there any option/method/idea to show all menu dynamically as its working without cache ?

Comment: which cache extension are using ???

Comment: @Abdul I am using mirasvit full page cache

Comment: Depends on how your FPC handles it, but anything that is customer data unique to that person (session) needs to be holepunched and given private storage only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem as I am using  FPC Extension for cache.So i have added following code in this file:
/app/code/local/Mirasvit/Fpc/Model/Processor.php

Find below code in function _getRequestId()

> $this->_requestId = strtolower($this->_requestId);
>   And add below code before this line.

```
 $pageIdentifier =  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getHeaderPage();
                If($pageIdentifier == 'commercial-shop')
                {
                    $this->_requestId .= $del.'commercial';
                }
                else if ($pageIdentifier == 'retail-home'){
                    $this->_requestId .= $del.'retail';
                }
```

I have posted this answer because it may help some one.